# How to perform equivalent of an AJAX long-poll with Visualforce

Tags: visualforce, ajax

I have a web page that communicates with a node.js backend. I use AJAX to long-poll the server, allowing realtime updates to be received as they occur server-side.

Below is a simplification of my existing client-side code. What I'd like to know is whether there's an equivalent way of doing this with Visualforce/Apex, or can I even host my existing code somehow within an apex page? Any hints, examples or walkthroughs would be more than welcome - I have only been using the Force platform for 3 days so I am still extremely unfamiliar with the technology, terminology, etc.

Also, the data I'm polling for is not Salesforce related, so I don't think the Streaming API will work because the whole topic/query concept is not applicable in this situation.

```
function poll() {

    longPollRequest = $.ajax({
        url: "http://myserver.com/longPoll",
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "jsonp",
        jsonpCallback: "localJsonpCallback",
        complete: function(jqXHR, textStatus ) {  
            poll(); // restart the poll
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {  }
    });
}

function localJsonpCallback(json) {
    // parse long-poll response
}
```

Comment: So you just want your VF page to subscribe to a 3rd party service? If so, have you tried any JavaScript libraries for that?

Comment: This isn't technically salesforce.com related at all, but in the spirit of helpfulness, I've included an answer here that may lead you down the right path.

Comment: @MikeChale Yep, that's essentially what I want to do. I haven't tried any JS libraries yet - I'm still working out what I can and can't do within a VF page.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at the [Streaming API](http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Getting_Started_with_the_Force.com_Streaming_API). You can have your VF page subscribe to a topic and get near real time updates. This [blog post](http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Getting_Started_with_the_Force.com_Streaming_API) does a really good job walking you through setting it up on your page.

Comment: Daniel, thanks for your suggestion. I probably should have been clearer in my question; the data that I'm expecting back from the server has absolutely nothing to do with Salesforce, so the whole idea of queries & topics doesn't really work in my situation. I tried embedding the above code inside a `<script>` block, but it never executed fully, possibly due to the asynchronous nature of `$.ajax()`. I also tried `sforce.connection.remoteFunction()` but it hung.

Answer (score 2):

You can't directly long-poll in Visualforce, except for the aforementioned Streaming API. There is a JavaScript proxy feature that salesforce.com provides, but it only works for single, short-lived requests. What you need is HTML5's `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header, with a value set to `*`. This needs to be implemented on the server-side-- the third-party server-- for this to work.

Basically, it's an extra HTTP header that is sent in a "pre-flight" request that validates if the connection should be allowed. By default, browsers will assume that a missing `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header value is the same as the `Host` header value. This effectively restricts XMLHttpRequest to only connecting to the host that originally served the page, to prevent cross-server scripting attacks.

Newer browsers support this header in the native XMLHttpRequest client (known as XMLHttpRequest Level 2). IE 8-9 support this through the XDomainRequest client, so you'll have to feature detect this if you want to support those browsers (*grumble grumble*). If you can't modify the server to emit this header, you may need to resort to your own proxy using a host that you can control to accept connections from salesforce.com and proxy the request to the destination server.

Answer (score 0):

Well I found a way to do it. I have no idea how acceptable it is as far as Salesforce coding practises go, but it worked for me. I haven't included a mechanism to stop the poll, but in my full implementation I issue an HTTP POST that tells my server to abort the poll.

## Page

```
<apex:page controller="longpollcontroller">
    <apex:form>
        <script>
        function doLongPoll() {
            Visualforce.remoting.Manager.invokeAction(
                '{!$RemoteAction.longpollcontroller.startLongPoll}',
                function (result, event) {
                    if (event.status) {
                        console.log(result); // show our results
                        doLongPoll(); // restart the poll
                    }
                }, {escape: false, timeout: 60000, buffer: false});
        }
        </script>
        <apex:outputPanel id="panel">
            <apex:commandButton onclick="doLongPoll();" value="Start Long Poll" rerender="panel" />
        </apex:outputPanel>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

## Controller

```
public class longpollcontroller {

    @RemoteAction public static 
    String startLongPoll() {
        String strResult = '{"defaultResp":"startLongPoll called"}';

        try {
            HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();

            req.setEndpoint('http://myLongPollURL');
            req.setMethod('GET');
            req.setTimeout(60000);

            Http http = new Http();
            HTTPResponse res = http.send(req);

            if (res.getStatusCode() == 200) {
                strResult = res.getBody();
            }
        }
        catch (CalloutException e) {
            strResult = '{"exception" : "' + e.getMessage() + '"}';
        }       

        return strResult;
    }
}
```